# Qual o período entre a tarde e a meia-noite?

Tags: vocabulário

Se o dia é a hora com luz do dia, ele é divido em manhã e tarde; a manhã começa no amanhecer e termina ao meio-dia, e a tarde começa ao meio-dia e termina no anoitecer. A noite tem a madrugada, que começa à meia-noite e termina no amanhecer.

Mas o que é o período entre a tarde e a meia-noite?

Comment: A primeira parte da noite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Resposta curta**

Esse período também é chamado "noite", só que num sentido mais restrito que "período sem luz" e que faz oposição a "madrugada" assim como "manhã" se opõe a "tarde".

`|                      dia                      |`

`|          dia          |         noite         |`

`|   manhã   |   tarde   |   noite   | madrugada |`

**Resposta longa**

Embora a resposta de Lambie resolva a questão, acredito que Schilive esteja atrás de um termo simples em vez de uma paráfrase. Abaixo exponho o porquê da resposta ser, a meu ver, "noite".

O que defendo neste texto é que tanto "dia" quanto "noite" têm significados mais amplos e mais específicos. A palavra "dia" se refere, inicialmente, ao período de 24h. Dentro desse intervalo, temos o período iluminado e o período escurecido. Eles se chamam "dia" e "noite", respectivamente, e aqui já vemos a primeira polissemia: "dia" (1), como período de 24h, e "dia" (2), como período iluminado.

É razoável indicar o *amanhecer* como o fim da noite e o início do dia (2) e o *anoitecer* como o fim do dia (2) e o início da noite.

Também está correto que o meio-dia divide o dia (2) em manhã e tarde. E é compreensível que se espere uma divisão parecida com o período noturno. Entretanto, não há duas palavras, para o período noturno, tão bem definidas e aceitas quanto "manhã" e "tarde" são para o período diurno. É verdade que temos "madrugada" para o período noturno entre meia-noite e o amanhecer, mas não há termo simples e *preciso* para o que é noite mas não é madrugada.

Acredito que a palavra mais usada seja mesmo "noite" (2), com a potencial ambiguidade resolvida pelo contexto de uso. Por exemplo, quando dizemos "à noite" ou "de noite", dependendo do contexto, não se espera que estejamos nos referindo à madrugada.

Nesse quesito, a língua portuguesa difere do inglês, do francês e do polonês, por exemplo, pois essas três são exemplos de línguas que possuem termos simples e (mais) precisos para se referir a esse período do dia: *evening*, *soir* e *wieczór*, respectivamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, HelioLBS, pela resposta! Eu não tinha lembrado que *noite* pode se referir ao período entre a tarde e a madrugada.